# Reduction of gingerol content in ginger using kitchen equipment

Tags: food-chemistry, extraction, phenols, taste

The single topic that this question focuses on is - how to remove gingerol and only gingerol from a piece of ginger in a manner that it remains safe to eat using equipment found in a well stocked domestic kitchen.

I found [Ref (1)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10942912.2015.1084633) which adds information to the question suggesting that several hours above the boiling point of water is required:

> After 3 h of heat treatment at 75, 100, and 125°C, the gingerol's content was reduced by 6.8, 12.6, and 42.7%, respectively, and the shogaol's content was increased by 2.95, 4.85, and 9.34 fold, respectively. After 3 h of heat treatment at 150°C, the gingerol's content was dramatically reduced by 89.5% and the increased shogaol's content was even lower than treatment at 125°C.

(See also [this article](http://ijps.aizeonpublishers.net/content/2016/1/ijps1344-1347.pdf))

Below I give some examples of things that I have tried.

I am trying to find out how to make preserved ginger without pungency.I assume the main thing is to break down the gingerol into safe products. Or extract it out into a fluid that can be discarded - without removing the other tastes. Experiments suggest that boiling in lemon juice has some effect. I suspect that the acidity is the operative principle. I have tried acetic acid - eg. white wine vinegar. Success is partial. Perhaps it should be heated under pressure or for a rather long time. And research suggests sodium chloride, sodium hydroxide, or potassium hydroxide.

What is the best, most effective and most safe, way to remove the pungency?

*References*

(1) Ho, S.-C.; Su, M.-S. Optimized Heat Treatment Enhances the Anti-Inflammatory Capacity of Ginger. *International Journal of Food Properties* 2016, **19** (8), 1884–1898. https://doi.org/10.1080/10942912.2015.1084633.

Comment: I rather doubt you can selectively remove gingerol and leave other flavouring compounds intact. From the structure gingerol is likely to be soluble in organics such as acetone, ethyl acetate and ether.

Comment: @Waylander given that it used to be very common to do so - I suspect that it is possible. Although I wonder that there might be multiple kinds of ginger and that this will effect the outcome. I will keep the options you suggest in mind, but they don't sound food safe. Would you say they are?

Comment: It's too broad not because of asking many questions, but because of not having a definite answer. This is even borderline off-topic. Could be considered "food chemistry", but food processing is just cooking, so ask a cook how to prepare it to be more tasty.

Comment: @PonderStibbons  Acetone is used as nail varnish remover and occurs within the body

Comment: @Mithoron So, would a question about how to remove caffeine from coffee beans be an appropriate question here? Or would this be "cooking"?

Comment: @Waylander Acetone is absolutely not applicable to food. Is even withdrawn from use in  nail varnish removers.

Comment: @BuckThorn I somehow doubt OP has access to supercritical extraction gear. There are reasons why common "chemical" solvents are not used in food processing. If you know an actual method of processing of ginger that can be used for small amounts at home, that go on and reopen.

Comment: @Mithoron  Acetone is still widely sold in the UK for nail varnish removal by major retailers, example   https://www.boots.com/boots-nail-polish-remover-200ml-10305366

Comment: @Mithoron The OP should be more clear about the scope of the problem, in other words. Hexane is still used in food processing: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36360023/ (and no, I do not recommend use at home, even if managing to obtain some).

Comment: Here is a good start for learning about ginger: https://www.compoundchem.com/2014/11/27/

Comment: @Mithoron I am definitely tackling this as a chemistry question and I did tag it food-chemistry which is a tag that already existed. You seem to be saying it is off topic rather than unfocused - that is that a chemist here could not answer it. My reason for asking here is that it is not about making food more tasty and the members at stack exchange cookery could not answer it. It is a request for information that an industrial food chemist would have. It is the sort of question Nile Red would tackle. I believe he would be said to be a chemist.

Comment: @Mithoron I have added a statement that it is about processing using domestic equipment. However, knowledge of an industrial process would be useful to me anyway.

Comment: @Karsten Thanks. Mostly that was stuff I already know. But I was interested in this "Cooking produces zingerone, which is less pungent, and is characteristic of the ginger flavour found in gingerbread." which at least acknowledges what I am looking for. But, I have cooked ginger for an hour in various solutions - and it still did not remove the "fresh ginger" taste.

Comment: Are you using old or [young](https://www.justonecookbook.com/young-ginger/) ginger?

Comment: @Karsten since it is fibrous, it is likely older ginger. Of course, I have a long list of options to try. I am dubious that the answer is young ginger - as the taste I am looking for is more earthy and complex, a clove or cinnamon aromatic spice (that is not hot "spicey") taste. It is a complex and almost earthy taste of gingerbread, not the taste of ginger you get with sushi. But, I am open to suggestions. Especially since the product I know of is not fibrous. However boiling in lemon juice did reduce the fibre.

Comment: @Karsten "Cooking ginger transforms gingerol via a reverse aldol reaction into zingerone". It appears that what I am looking for is a high component of zingerone, which is produced by heat treating gingerol - but you need several hours above the boiling point of water (as atmospheric pressure) to convert enough of the gingerol to zingerone.

Comment: @mithron were you involved in the closing of the question? I just ask because I would like to be able to argue that it should be opened again. I know have enough information to answer the question myself. It is not a complicated indeterminate issue - it is a very precise and specific one. And the answer is - heat treatment above 150 degrees Celsius for several hours.

Comment: related post in meta: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5296/when-should-i-vote-to-close

Comment: Question is still open-ended and "heat treatment above 150 degrees Celsius for several hours" of food is hardly a good idea.

Comment: Maybe an enzymatic path would make more sense.  Aldolases exist, but I don’t know about them in a kitchen scenario (different from invertases, which are available in food grade).